# Nested promises with multiple return values

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to switch from [Async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async) to [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promises (performance reason, and also because I think promises are more elegant, but that's another discussion).

I have the following code in Async.waterfall:

```
async.waterfall([
    function callGoogle(next) {
        request.get(config.google.meEndpoint, {
            auth: {bearer: req.body.access_token},
            json: true
        }, next);
    },
    function handleGoogleResponse(response, body, next) {
        //error handling

        next(null, body);
    },
    function queryDatabase(googleUserInfo, next) {
        googleUserModel
            //.findOne(...), etc.
            .exec(function (err, usr) {
                next(err, usr, googleUserInfo);
            });
    },
    function handleUser(googleUser, googleUserInfo, next) {
        //googleUser is my internal representation of a user logged in using Google
        //googleUserInfo is the information provided by Google
        //If googleUser exists, I'm done, otherwise I can use googleUserInfo to create a new googleUser
    }], function done());
```

The problem I'm facing is that using promises, I get something like this:

```
httpGet(config.google.meEndpoint, {
    auth: {bearer: req.body.access_token},
    json: true
}).spread(function handleGoogleResponse(response, body){
    //error handling

    return body;
}).then(function queryDatabase(googleUserInfo){
    return googleUserModel
        //.findOne(...), etc.
        .execAsync();
}).then(function handleUser(googleUser){
    //I don't have access to the previous then's googleUserInfo!
});
```

My queryDatabase function has a nested promise (`execAsync`), so the next `then` will only get the googleUserModel returned by mongoose.

How can I cascade arguments down a promise chain?

Comment: Promises are more elegant than waterfalls? That's not a discussion, that's a fact! :-)

Comment: In addition to @BenjaminGruenbaum linked join pattern, I recently covered both value and join patterns used to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28176898/995876